# JQuery UI Drag & Drop without dropping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm new to jQuery UI and I don't really need to drop anything but a specific data attribute from the dragged element. With that data I will build a new element inside the drop element.

My html looks like:

```
<div class="dropElem">
    <div class="cod">Empty</div>
    ..elements i will populate later..
</div>

<div class="dragElem" data-cod='cod1'>
    <div>Data</div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="dragElem" data-cod='cod2'>
    <div>Data</div>
    ...
</div>
```

and my Javascript is like this:

```
$('.dragElem').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "true",
    cursorAt: {top: 0, left: 0},//mandatory for my css structure
    start: function (event, ui) {
        var clone = $(ui.helper);
        clone.addClass('helper')//class added to style the helper
    }
});

$('.dropElem').droppable({
    activeClass: "activeDrop",
    hoverClass: "hoverActiveDrop",
    tolerance: "pointer",//mandatory for my css structure
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var cod = ui.helper.data('cod'));
        //make new elements based on data received
     }
 });
```

Basically I use helper's dragging visual effect to transport data from one element to another.

What I need to do after drop is to disable the dragged element from being dragged again (I will add a class to highlight this) and to disable the droppped-in elemen from receiving any other dragElem (I will add a class to it too).

PS: I'm also not sure if `var cod = ui.helper.data('cod'));` is the best way to grab the data-attribute.

Any suggetion will be appreciated!

Comment: add a class (or data-attribute, ..) to the dragged element on drop. check if the element to drag has the class in the `start` function of the draggable -> if so `return false` to cancel the draggable. (http://jsfiddle.net/Lwu3zm3t/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a class in the [`cancel`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) option and add that particular class to the draggable inside the drop callback to prevent further dragging. For disabling the droppable, you can use the [`disable`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#method-disable) method:

```js
$('.dragElem').draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "true",
  cancel: ".disable"
});

$('.dropElem').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var cod = ui.draggable.addClass("ui-state-disabled").data('cod');
    console.log(cod);
    $(this).droppable("disable");
  }
});
```

```css
.dragElem {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  background: hotpink;
}
.dropElem {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="dropElem"></div>
<div class="dragElem" data-cod='cod1'>
  <div>1</div>
</div>
<div class="dragElem" data-cod='cod2'>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks T J, i figured it out by myself but I did almost the same you suggest, i will mark your answer as accepted!